# Div backgroundImage cropped with backgroundPosition and all filled

Tags: css, image, background-image, background-position, background-size

How to fill all `div` with a background image that is cropped using `background-position` with `CSS`?
I tried `background-size: cover;` but it's not working, the image is cropped but not fully filling the `div`.

EDIT:
Now my code looks like:

```
background-size: cover, cover;
    background-position: -12px -8px, center center, center center;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;    
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
```

backgrount-position is different for different images in background-image

First div have:

```
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover,cover;
background-position: center center;
transition: height ease-in-out 0.3s;
```

Comment: have you tried background-size: 100% 100%;

Comment: Yes, no difference. I updated my question with code

Comment: please post the html markup, so i can try to help you.

Comment: Use background-size: cover; (with one "cover")

Comment: Use `cover` only once